# How do I define validation rules in laravel 8 globally?

Tags: php, laravel

I have considered defining validation rules for different parts of my application in a class as static variables. For example,

```
$VALIDATION_RULES = [
    'signatures' => [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'max:255', 'required','string'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'max:255', 'required', 'string'],
        'enabled' => [ 'required', Rule::in(['on', 'off']) ],
        'signature_file' => ['required', 'mimes:png,jpeg,jpg', 'max:1024'],
        'operator_id' => ['required', 'numeric'],
    ],
];
```

However, I get this error.

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Constant expression contains invalid operations
```

This is due to

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be
> initialized using a literal or constant before PHP 5.6; expressions
> are not allowed. In PHP 5.6 and later, the same rules apply as const
> expressions: some limited expressions are possible, provided they can
> be evaluated at compile time.

according to the php official documentation.
What is the correct way to do this?

P.S.: This variable is defined inside a class as a public and static member. In the code, wherever I need to validate an input, I can call

`$validated_input = $request->validate($VALIDATION_RULES['signatures']);`

This way, I can have all the rules centralized in one class.

Comment: You can use global scope, which will execute every model request.

Comment: where have you defined  the ```$VALIDATION_RULES```. Can you share the whole file

Comment: Do you want to have a part of a code and use it in the other FormRequests too?

Comment: I would suggest creating your own Validator model or FormRequest that you can use to extend other validators or formrequests

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai In side a class as a public static variable

Comment: @mohammadmahdibaleghsefat yes. I want to have a centralized set of validation rules.

Comment: @aynber You mean that I define separate validator models for each model in the code? Could you please give me some links on the related documentation?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation shows how to create validators and form requests

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a part of a code and use it in the other FormRequests too, you can use traits.

Suppose you want to validate users in the multi FormRequests:

Create `UserRequestTrait` and add this method to the trait:

```
private function userInfoValidator(string $prefix = ''): array
{
    return [
        $prefix . 'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
        $prefix . 'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
    ];

}
```

Now you can use it in the FormRequest classes:

```
class UserFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use UserRequestTrait;


    public function rules()
    {

        $rules = [
          // Add the other rules
        ];

        // validate user info
        $userValidation = $this->userInfoValidator();

        return array_merge(
            $rules,
            $userValidation
        );
    }
}
```

And if you are validating an object, you can add the prefix in the `userInfoValidator` method, like this:

```
$userValidation = $this->userInfoValidator('users.*.');
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `functions` ,`expressions`,`objects` while declaring class properties (includes `static` and `non-static` property).which means you cannot call `someFunction()` or `new Sampleclass`  inside the property, you can only use static values. You'll have to add those values differently inside the `constructor` or maybe some other method.

so By removing `Rule::in(['on', 'off'])`  inside the property (which is **object**) will fix the issue

```
    class MyTestClass {
  
  public $VALIDATION_RULES = [
    'signatures' => [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'max:255', 'required','string'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'max:255', 'required', 'string'],
        'enabled' => [ 'required'],
        'signature_file' => ['required', 'mimes:png,jpeg,jpg', 'max:1024'],
        'operator_id' => ['required', 'numeric'],
    ],
];
    
}

$obj = new MyTestClass;
dd($obj);
```

You can read the docs

https://php-legacy-docs.zend.com/manual/php5/en/language.oop5.static